# Feign client authentication using NTLM(pass domain along with username and password)

Tags: spring-boot, dynamics-crm, ntlm, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am using Feign Client in muy Spring Boot Application and trying to figure out how to do NTLM authentication using BasicAuthRequestInterceptor. Was able to establish authentication between various springboot microservices using BasicAuthRequestInterceptor by passing username and password. Now I need to make a REST call to Microsoft Dynamics crm but the catch is Dynamics CRM uses NTML authentication which requires passing domain along with username and password. So wondering if any one came across this use case and if so please provide your inputs. Thank you